# Javascript checkbox if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox

I wanted to trigger an if condition based on a checked or unchecked checkbox, by clicking a button.
The code segments of interest are:

```
 Out-Projekt: <input type= "checkbox" id= "OUT"> <br> <br>
 <button  class = "buttonz" onclick = "berechnung()">Berechnen </button>          

<script>
 function berechnung() {
 var OUT = parseInt(document.getElementById("OUT").checked);

if( checkbox.checked == true){ code}
 else { code }
}
</script>
```

For some reason, it does not work. I read other topics regarding this but found nothing suitable. Hope someone can help

Comment: `if( checkbox.checked` But you never defined a variable named `checkbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking to see if the `input` assigned to variable `checkbox` is checked, but you didn't define that variable.

```html
Out-Projekt: <input type= "checkbox" id= "OUT"> <br> <br>
 <button  class = "buttonz" onclick = "berechnung()">Berechnen </button>          

<script>
function berechnung() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById("OUT");

  if( checkbox.checked === true){
    console.log('checked');
  } else { 
    console.log('not checked');
  }
}
</script>
```